# Laravel 4 - Adding ID values to dropdown selects

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Im trying to use the built in dropdown HTML helper, but i cant find how to add the id="idvalue"

The documentation give this example,

```
echo Form::select('size', array('L' => 'Large', 'S' => 'Small'));
```

When i try the following code, i get errors

```
echo Form::select('size', array('L' => 'Large', 'S' => 'Small'), 'id' => 'idvalue');
```

Im using Laravel 4.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the source code of FormBuilder.php:

```
/**
 * Create a select box field.
 *
 * @param  string  $name
 * @param  array   $list
 * @param  string  $selected
 * @param  array   $options
 * @return string
 */
 public function select($name, $list = array(), $selected = null, $options = array());
```

So you should call

```
 echo Form::select('size', array('key' => 'value'), 'default', array('id' => 'ID_HERE'));
```

Comment: @Ryu_hayabusa better?

Answer (score 1):

The easy answer

```
echo Form::select('size', array('L' => 'Large', 'S' => 'Small'), 'L', array('id' => 'idvalue'));
```

fourth parameter must be an array

Answer (score 0):

```
{!! Form::select('designation_id', $designations, old('designation_id'), 
                 ['class' => 'form-control',  'required', 'id' => '#designation']) !!}
```

you can add like this